# Building jQuery multi select questionnaire

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I have to build jQuery  multi select questionnaire .
The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head lang="en">
    <meta ccontent="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>multi select questionnaire</title>


    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<div id="questions">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentQuestion = null;
    var questionIndex = 0;

    // Your list of questions. Each question has an answer (either a,b or c)
    // and then a set of "options" in the question
    var questions = [
        {
            'answer': 'c',
            'question': 'What doesn\'t fit?',
            options: ['Dog', 'Capybara', 'Pizza']
        },
        {
            'answer': 'b',
            'question': 'What is 9*9',
            options: ['9', '81', '99']
        }
    ];

    // Detect when the submit button is clicked and check if the question
    // was answered correctly
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        var val = $('#questions').find('input:checked').val();
        if(currentQuestion) {
            if(currentQuestion.answer == val) {
                alert("Nice work!");
                showQuestion();
            } else {
                alert("Nope!");
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    // Set the value of an option in the question
    function setRadioLabel(radioId, text) {
        $('label[for="' + radioId + '"]').find('span.ui-btn-text').text(text);
    };

    // Show a random question
    function showQuestion() {
        // Grab next question, and increment so we get a new one next time
        var random = questions[questionIndex++ % questions.length];

        $('#question').text(random.question);

        $('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');

        setRadioLabel('radio1', random.options[0]);
        setRadioLabel('radio2', random.options[1]);
        setRadioLabel('radio3', random.options[2]);
        currentQuestion = random;
    };

    // Start the question stuff off
    showQuestion();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't display nothing on the page because I got the following error  in the line  `$('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');`:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
This is the only error I got, and can't figure what is the problem.

Comment: `checkboxradio()` is part of jQuery Mobile, not plain jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar - you right. I added the library of jQuery Mobile and there is no error, but I see in the Network that ajax-loader.gif is not modified